# How to Using Twitter with OAuth On Android tablet Layout Screen

Tags: layout, twitter, oauth, screen, tablet

Twitter with OAuth On Android tablet Layout Screen
Coz layout screen is very small.
On Samsung Tab Screen size is to small on my tab code.